# How is it Possbile to run Groovy class together with java classes using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, groovy, gradle, spring-boot

I am trying to run my spring-boot app (using gradle and java) together with groovy classes.

So I added controller (as shown in the examples)

the controller is under `src/main/groovy`

```
@RestController
class ThisWillActuallyRun {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        "Hello World!"
    }

}
```

I also have my java classes under

```
src/main/java
```

Iam running spring boot using java -jar (or gradle in dev mode: bootRun)

Code is compiled but the groovy controller isnt loaded.

I miss some concept here about running groovy and java classes side-by-side on the same jar?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that your groovy classes are in the generated jar? There is no difference once the classes are compiled and packaged.

Comment: what are the packages used in both roots (because of component scan)?

Comment: Hi @rayman has my answer helped you out?

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to apply the groovy gradle plugin.
I have replicated your simptoms by creating a spring boot project with both java and groovy classes, and only applying the java plugin.
To be able to include groovy classes in your application, replace

```
apply plugin: "java"
```

with

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
```

The groovy plugin subclasses the java plugin, so you will still able to compile java classes.

If that is not the case, you will have to provide more information, like the gradle build script. If you are using gradle.